# Apache on XAMPP isn't working

Tags: apache, xampp

I downloaded XAMPP but I can't start Apache. I tried to change the port number from 80 to 81 and also listen 443 to listen 444 but it doesn't work. I quit Skype already. When I checked what's on the port 80, it shows that a file named httpd.exe is running. I tried to stop it using the task manager but it still doesn't stop and it always shows this message when I tried to run it

22:59:17  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by ""C:\httpd-2.4.7-win32-VC11\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice" with PID 2268!

22:59:17  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!

22:59:17  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application

22:59:17  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

I've already installed Apache before installing XAMPP. Should I uninstall it?

Answer (score 0):

Try going into your apache folder inside the xampp folder and running the apache_uninstallservice.bat and then apache_installservice.bat